# Installing Cordova Push Notifications Plugin in Visual Studio

Tags: android, visual-studio, cordova, phonegap-pushplugin

I tried days to solve the problem with using cordova push plugin.
After installing the plugin using visual studio config.xml I get this error :

[image]

Now after I delete this piece of code from my config.xml :

```
  <vs:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.PushPlugin" version="2.5.0" />
```

It build but i can't use plugin .
How can i avoid this error ? 
And is it necessary to have this line of code in my config.xml ?

Comment: hmmm, I found an answer with simple googling ... Did you tried ... Question was asked 13h ago, here on SO ...

Comment: could you please send me its link ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution for those who have the same problem like me.
As it was my problem for weeks I describe the solution .

It seems  that Visual Studio can't add the plugin PushPlugin v2.5.0 . 
So for those who has this issue it's recommended to use the previous version.

Version 2.4.0 which works perfectly fine can be found from this link :

https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin/releases/tag/2.4.0